# Comparing date time with current datetime

Tags: javascript

From server I am getting a date time like this format "Thu, 02-Jan-2020 08:32:18 GMT" and I want to compare it current GMT date time . How I will do that in javascript.

Comment: [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const serverDate = new Date('Thu, 02-Jan-2020 08:32:18 GMT');
const clientDate = new Date();
const clientOffset = clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000; // get milliseconds from minutes

if (serverDate.getTime() > clientDate.getTime() + clientOffset) {
  console.log('serverDate is later than clientDate');
} else {
  console.log('serverDate is earlier than clientDate');
}
```

Here we are using built-in [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method from this example is used to get the number of milliseconds passed since January 1st, 1970. This way we ended up just comparing 2 numbers.

If you set different timezone on a client device than GMT+0 on the server, [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) comes to help. It returns the number of minutes we need to add to the `getTime()` result so that the client timestamp will also be in GMT+0 timezone.

Comment: I am getting Thu, 02-Jan-2020 08:32:18 GMT from server which is one hour later time from now and my browser returning Thu Jan 02 2020 13:28:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) this as recent time but my local time need to be one hour less than the time getting from server so that the comparison work correctly

Comment: Utpal, I've updated the answer to eliminate timezone difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Using it is as simple as for example x.isSameAs(y), x.isBefore(y) x.isAfter(y)